# Как реализовать загрузку страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, xhr

Как реализовать загрузку страницы через `XMLHttpRequest`?
А именно, имеется в `index.php` вот такой код:

```
<?php  
// Здесь подключается главная страница 
include("main.html");

// Сами страницы
switch($_GET['action']){
    case "page1":
      include("page1.html");
    break;
}

// Footer
echo '</body><footer></footer>';
?>
```

В `main.html` такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
   <button onclick="ajax.load();">

   <div id="content"><!-- Сюда должны загружаться страницы  --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kак сделать, чтобы когда грузишь через AJAX, `main.html` не попадал в `content`, а когда через браузерную строку, тоже выводилось корректно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае ajax **include** работать не будет

```
<?php
// Здесь подключается главная страница
include("main.html");

// Сами страницы
switch($_GET['action']){
    case "page1":
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !== 'XMLHttpRequest') {
            include("page1.html");
        }
        break;
}

// Footer
echo '</body><footer></footer>';
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую !

Comment: @5grrthrthrh Если у вас для всех страниц планируется такая логика как вы описали в вопросе, то условие на проверку ajax нужно вывести до switch